# Remove laravel/ui and php artisan ui vue --auth in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I installed the `laravel/ui` and `php artisan ui vue --auth` in my laravel projec, but now I want them removed. How do I do it?

Using `composer update vendor/package-name` didn't work and the `auth` folders still exist.

Comment: `laravel/ui` publish  file to project not in vender file so you need to manually delete those file

Comment: Auto delete of folders/files out of the vendor won't happen > with composer remove PACKAGE you can remove it from the vendor but any other files copied/updated will remain as they are. In case you got GIT you can compare what have/how been modified and to revert it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the package by running `composer remove laravel/ui` but you need to manually need to remove blade and controller files. **Also, you need to update the `web.php` route file.**

Comment: Thanks for this. I edited the answer to focus on editing the route files. Seems like `Auth::routes()` have to be manually erased from `web.php`

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove this from `composer.json` then run the `composer update` command.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bhagchandani said, first run:

```bash
composer remove laravel/ui
```

And, manually remove each generated controller, blade files, edit route web file,
and in addition to that, remove each generated CSS, SASS, and JavaScript files in `/resources` (if any).

Then, make sure to remove every dependency related to vue in `package.json`, and run, to update the node dependencies:

```bash
npm i
```